# Use realm in aar-library

Tags: android, realm, aar

We have a library that implements Realm. When we export the library to an AAR file and import it in a project we need to add this to the 
project gradle file outside of the library:

```
classpath 'io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:1.0.0'
```

and to the application gradle file itself:

```
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

This is not a nice way to implement a library in your application since you have to do more than just import the aar dependency.

Is there a cleaner way to implement an AAR library with Realm?

Comment: You can use Realm Modules for isolating your Realm usage to your library. Please take a look at https://github.com/realm/realm-java/tree/master/examples/moduleExample/library

Comment: Thank you but this is not the problemen were facing. We want to export the library as an AAR and then import it in other projects. This part doesnt work smooth because Realm is not exported in the AAR file which leaves us with no other choice then adding the dependencies in the project, but that is not a neat solution for a library.

Comment: realm-plugin is more than just a jar lib, it also includes an annotation processor, a byte-code transformer, and some so files for different ABIs. It would be very difficult to include everything into an AAR. Also, if so, you might meet a Realm version conflicts if user also use Realm for the other part of app. So please use Realm module instead, and let the app developer choose which version of Realm to use.

Comment: @Doppie did you find a solution for this?